# Is there a batch mode command for maven branch?

Tags: maven, branch

I have a parent pom with list of modules. Each module has a <parent> section with version number of a parent. 
First I do a release, which creates tag with version without SNAPSHOT and then I want to create a branch from that tag. The problem is that maven keeps asking about version number for each module. Is there a way to make maven set all modules to the same version?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the release plugin, and by 'do a release' you mean run

```
mvn release:prepare release:perform
```

then you can add the autoVersionSubmodules flag, as follows:

```
mvn release:prepare release:perform -DautoVersionSubmodules=true
```

This will set the version of all your child projects to the version you accept for the parent. Or if you just want to accept all the defaults, you can use the --batch-mode option. See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/non-interactive-release.html for details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [release:branch](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-release-plugin/examples/branch.html) goal instead of release:prepare